# Is there a tf.keras.optimizers implementation for L-BFGS?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, subclassing

Does anybody have a Tensorflow 2 tf.keras subclass for the L-BFGS algorithm? If one wants to use L-BFGS, one has currently two (official) options:

1. TF Probability
2. SciPy optimization

These two options are quite cumbersome to use, especially when using custom models. So I am planning to implement a custom subclass of tf.keras.optimizers to use L-BFGS. But before I start, I was curious, whether somebody already tackled this task?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented an interface between keras and SciPy optimize.
https://github.com/pedro-r-marques/keras-opt

I'm using 'cg' by default but you should also be able to use 'l-bfgs'. Take a look at the unit tests for example usage. I will add documentation as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody have a Tensorflow 2 tf.keras subclass for the L-BFGS algorithm?

Yes, here's (yet another) implementation L-BFGS (and *any* other `scipy.optimize.minimize` solver) for your consideration in case it fits your use case:

- https://pypi.org/project/kormos/
- https://github.com/mbhynes/kormos

This package has a similar goal to Pedro's answer above, but I would recommend it over the `keras-opt` package if you run into issues with memory consumption during training. I implemented `kormos` when trying to build a Rendle-type factorization machine and kept OOMing with other full-batch solver implementations.

> These two options are quite cumbersome to use, especially when using custom models. So I am planning to implement a custom subclass of tf.keras.optimizers to use L-BFGS. But before I start, I was curious, whether somebody already tackled this task?

Agreed, it's a little cumbersome to fit the signatures of `tfp` and `scipy` into the parameter fitting procedure in `keras`, because of the way that `keras` steps in and out of an optimizer that has persistent state between calls, which is not how most [old school?] optimization libraries work.

This is addressed specifically in the `kormos` package since IMO during prototyping it's a pretty common workflow to alternate between *either* a stochastic optimizer and a full-batch deterministic optimizer, and this should be simple enough to do ad hoc in the python interpreter.

The package has models that extend `keras.Model` and `keras.Sequential`:

- [`kormos.models.BatchOptimizedModel`](https://kormos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#kormos.models.BatchOptimizedModel)
- [`kormos.models.BatchOptimizedSequentialModel`](https://kormos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#kormos.models.BatchOptimizedSequentialModel)

These can be compiled to be fit with *either* the standard or the `scipy` solvers; it would look something like this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from kormos.models import BatchOptimizedSequentialModel

# Create an Ordinary Least Squares regressor
model = BatchOptimizedSequentialModel()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
  units=1,
  input_shape=(5,),
))

# compile the model for stochastic optimization
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="sgd")
model.fit(...)

# compile the model for deterministic optimization using scipy.optimize.minimize
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="L-BFGS-B")
model.fit(...)
```