# What's the replacement for ScipyOptimizerInterface in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I want to experiment with [Manumorph - A Tensorflow implementation of Deep Painterly Harmonization](https://github.com/sarahmfrost/manumorph).

Unfortunately, I had zero success so far. I followed the instructions, but the current version of Tensorflow is not compatible with this implementation. I already updated the code with the Tensorflow tool `tf_upgrade_v2.py`. The script reported that `tensorflow. contrib` is not supported anymore.

I also tried installing Tensorflow 1.15 but this version gives me DLL errors that I don't know how to solve.

I am new to Tensorflow and don't know what any of the code does. I hope someone with experience in Tensorflow can tell how I can make the line

```
train_step = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, 
                        var_list=[combination_im], 
                        options={'maxfun':20})
```

in `main.py` work with Tensorflow 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Scipy Optimizer with Tensorflow 2.0 for Neural Network training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029854/use-scipy-optimizer-with-tensorflow-2-0-for-neural-network-training)

Comment: As I said I have no experience with Tensorflow. What I need is an exact copy-paste solution. In other words I need "train_step  = *whatever I have to put here*". For example, what do I do with var_list in your example?

Comment: In Tensorflow 2.0, Few of the `tf.contrib` libraries are moved to Tensorflow addons and few of them to Tensorflow probability. `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface`replace with `tfp.optimizer.nelder_mead_minimize`. For more details on the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/nelder_mead_minimize). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Left this same answer in [Use Scipy Optimizer with Tensorflow 2.0 for Neural Network training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59029854/use-scipy-optimizer-with-tensorflow-2-0-for-neural-network-training))

If you'd like something even more drag-and-drop for interfacing TF2 with solvers from `scipy.optimize.minimize` solver) you could take a look at this and see if it fits your use case:

- https://pypi.org/project/kormos/
- https://github.com/mbhynes/kormos